# HTML div auto width

Tags: html

I have a container div and 3 inner divs that places them all in one row. The side divs have fixed width and I want auto width for the middle div. This is my code:

```
<div style="width: auto; height: 25px; position: relative; float: right;">
    <div style="width: 25px; height:25p; float: right; position: relative; display:inline-block;">
    <div style="width: auto; height: 25px; position: relative; float: right; display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div style="width: 25px; height:25p; float: right; position: relative; display:inline-block;">
</div>
```

...but middle div doesn't take any space.

**note: I don't want the container div to have fixed or percentage size.**

What is the solution?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: middle div doesn't occupy the free space between two aside divs even when I make it's width 100%.

Comment: (add an @ and my name if you wright a comment so I see it faster) try with closing the aside divs as Christoffer sayd! also height:25p; will never work. you have to wright height:25px;

Comment: @caramba : Ok, Thank you. I have one problem with Christoffer's offer yet. max-width that I don't want it.

Comment: there is no max-width!?

Comment: @caramba : No, I don't want max-width. But I think this is impossible probably, and then I should use max-width after all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not closing off the first and last div within the container. You need that. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qC5bk/), I think it is what you need. Here is the code:

```
<style>
div {
    width: auto;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
div div {
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;

}
div div:first-child {
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
}
div div:last-child {
    width: 25px;
    float: right;
}
</style>

<div>
<div>1</div>
<div>This is the second and middle div.</div>
<div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want middle div change his width with it's content. It mus depends on container width. In other words middle div must fill free space within container div.

Comment: There is no "free space" as you havn't declared the width of the container. If you do that (ie 100%) you can make the middle container fill out this space. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qC5bk/3/

Comment: I changed width value of container to 100%, but middle div don't occupy the free space :(

Comment: Thank you. If in your example, we can omit max-width this will be exactly what I wish. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue before. I spent a lot of time playing around, and luckily it was a simple fix:

```
<style>
div1{
float: left;
width: 200px;         /* ...Or whatever fixed width you want */
}

div2{
overflow: hidden;    /* This will automatically set this div's width to the remainder */
}
</style>
```

Hope that helps.